# Change the shortcut for Inserting a New Equation in MS Word for Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, ms-office, shortcut

I am having trouble changing the shortcut to add a new equation in MS Word for Mac.

Currently, the shortcut is set to: Control + =

I want to change this to the new shortcut: Shift + E

As per my findings on the internet, the procedure to do so is:

Word >> Tools >> Customise Keyboard and then search the command am looking to add/delete shortcut for and then edit it.

So when I do this, I go to the Category of:  Insert >> InsertEquation

Now the problem is, neither do I see the existing shortcut which should appear in "Current Keys" text box as visible in the screenshot, nor can I add a new shortcut in the "Press new keyboard shortcut" textfield, visible in the same screenshot. (My new shortcut does not show up in the text field even when I press it, so the Assign button next to it is greyed out and can't be pressed)

Help me solve this please

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Keyboard to reassign[image]
(i dont have my mac with me but this shows the idea)